Networkpolicies not working in self-provisioned Kubernetes

I am very puzzled with the network policy not working in my self-provisioned kubernetes. Do you know what is wrong with my cluster?
kubectl describe ds weave-net -n=kube-system
Name:           weave-net
Selector:       name=weave-net
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         name=weave-net
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 3
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 3
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 3
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 3
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  3 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           name=weave-net
  Service Account:  weave-net
  Init Containers:
   weave-init:
    Image:      weaveworks/weave-kube:latest
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /home/weave/init.sh
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /host/etc from cni-conf (rw)
      /host/home from cni-bin2 (rw)
      /host/opt from cni-bin (rw)
      /lib/modules from lib-modules (rw)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
  Containers:
   weave:
    Image:      weaveworks/weave-kube:latest
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /home/weave/launch.sh
    Requests:
      cpu:      50m
    Readiness:  http-get http://127.0.0.1:6784/status delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      INIT_CONTAINER:  true
      HOSTNAME:         (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /host/etc/machine-id from cni-machine-id (ro)
      /host/var/lib/dbus from dbus (ro)
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
      /weavedb from weavedb (rw)
   weave-npc:
    Image:      weaveworks/weave-npc:latest
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Requests:
      cpu:  50m
    Environment:
      HOSTNAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
    Mounts:
      /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
  Volumes:
   weavedb:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/weave
    HostPathType:  
   cni-bin:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /opt
    HostPathType:  
   cni-bin2:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home
    HostPathType:  
   cni-conf:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc
    HostPathType:  
   cni-machine-id:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/machine-id
    HostPathType:  
   dbus:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /var/lib/dbus
    HostPathType:  
   lib-modules:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:  
   xtables-lock:
    Type:               HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:               /run/xtables.lock
    HostPathType:       FileOrCreate
  Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Events:                 <none

kubectl describe networkpolicies
Name:         default-deny
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2024-10-11 15:37:38 +0000 UTC
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app in (tictacktoe-app-deployment,tictacktoe2-app-deployment)
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    <none> (Selected pods are isolated for ingress connectivity)
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress

kubectl describe deployment tictacktoe-app-deployment  ticktacktoe2-app-deployment

Name:                   tictacktoe-app-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 11 Oct 2024 14:23:54 +0000
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=tictacktoe-app-deployment
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=tictacktoe-app-deployment
  Containers:
   tictacktoe3-app:
    Image:        doomcarnage/react_tictacktoe-app:1.0.0
    Port:         3000/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   tictacktoe-app-deployment-5b46dd9ccc (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>


Name:                   tictacktoe2-app-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 11 Oct 2024 14:24:05 +0000
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=tictacktoe2-app-deployment
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=tictacktoe2-app-deployment
  Containers:
   tictacktoe4-app:
    Image:        doomcarnage/react_tictacktoe-app:1.0.0
    Port:         3000/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   tictacktoe2-app-deployment-5566485644 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>

kubectl describe service tictacktoe3-app-service tictacktoe4-apps-service

Name:                     tictacktoe3-app-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=tictacktoe-app-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.101.210.35
IPs:                      10.101.210.35
Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30000/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.9:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>


Name:                     tictacktoe4-app-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=tictacktoe2-app-deployment
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.106.200.225
IPs:                      10.106.200.225
Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30001/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.2.15:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Note that I am expected a network block but after running the below command, I get a successful response.
kubectl exec tictacktoe-app-deployment-5b46dd9ccc-9dcfb -it -- curl http://10.244.2.15:3000/


<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>Document</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.ba5dffa2.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.9c5c5444.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>


Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
